# Cygwin install error: Package file libxxx has a corrupt local copy, please remove and retry

Tags: cygwin

When attempting to install certain packages to Cygwin, I received one of the following errors:

> Package file libgcc1 has a corrupt local copy, please remove and retry.
>
> Package file libssp0 has a corrupt local copy, please remove and retry.
>
> Package file libstc++6 has a corrupt local copy, please remove and retry.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer. Instead answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: This may well be a temporary problem with cygwin, better suited to be answered to and searched for in the mailing lists (archives) at www.cygwin.com

Answer (score 2):

If this happens to you, the easiest solution is to delete the **Local Package Directory** that the Cygwin installer uses to download and install the packages from. The directory name will look similar to your download site, e.g. "http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f"